# What is the rule of top\bottom\left\right attribution in css?

Tags: html, css

Set the top edge of the absolute positioned  element to 50px below the top edge of its nearest positioned ancestor in the following css code.

[image]

The css code is the following:

```
<html>
<header>
<style type="text/css">
*{margin:0 0 0 0;padding:0 0 0 0} 
div.block {
    width: 400px;
    height: 121px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    position:absolute;
    left:50px;
    top:50px;
    margin: auto ;
}
div.box{float:left;}
div img{margin:0px;padding:0;width:121px;height:121px;float:left;}
div.description{float:left;border 1px solid red;margin:10px  50px;}
</style>

</header>
<body>
    <div class="block">
        <div class="box"><img src="images/set06.jpg" /></div>  
        <div class="description">
                <p>music mane:  xxxxxxxx</p>
                <p>author:  yyyyyyyy</p>
                <p>publication：20081001</p>
                <p>language：english</p>
          </div>  
     </div>

</body>
</html>
```

I don't understand that displayed effect when to set

```
    bottom:50px;
    left:50px;
    right:50px;
    top:50px
```

in the css.
The div was set into the screen center such the same as

```
    bottom:0px;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
    top:0px
```

why  `bottom:50px;left:50px;right:50px;top:50px;`
        is equal to  `bottom:0px;left:0px;right:0px;top:0px;`?
What is the rule of  top\bottom\left\right  attribution in css?Why the div was set into screen center?Which result in that?

```
<html>
<header>
<style type="text/css">
*{margin:0 0 0 0;padding:0 0 0 0} 
div.block {
    width: 400px;
    height: 121px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:50px;
    left:50px;
    right:50px;
    top:50px;
    margin: auto ;
}
div.box{float:left;}
div img{margin:0px;padding:0;width:121px;height:121px;float:left;}
div.description{float:left;border 1px solid red;margin:10px  50px;}
</style>

</header>
<body>
    <div class="block">
        <div class="box"><img src="images/set06.jpg" /></div>  
        <div class="description">
                <p>music mane:  xxxxxxxx</p>
                <p>author:  yyyyyyyy</p>
                <p>publication：20081001</p>
                <p>language：english</p>
          </div>  
     </div>    
</body>
</html>
```

Please tell me more about the principle of top\bottom\left\right  attribution in css.

[image]

And last problem:
why

```
div.block {
width: 400px;
height: 121px;
border: 1px solid red;
position:absolute;
top:0px; 
left:0px
margin: auto ;
}
```

can't center in the screen?

why

```
div.block {
width: 400px;
height: 121px;
border: 1px solid red;
position:absolute;
top:0px; 
left:0px;
right:0px;
bottom:0px;
margin: auto ;
}
```

can center in the screen?
Please draw four lines to indicate the meaning of `top:0px; left:0px;right:0px;bottom:0px;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer this question, you need to understand how `position` and Box Model works. When you position an element absolutely, the element takes the `top`, `left`, `right`, and `bottom` values and position it accordingly.

So, consider that the `top` and `bottom` are `0`, then the element will be positioned `0px` from the top of the page and `0px` from the bottom of the page. That means, the element is positioned vertically centered. This is the same for `left` and `right`.

See the demo:

```css
.abs {position: absolute; top: 15px; bottom: 15px; left: 15px; right: 15px; background: #ccf;}
```

```html
<div class="abs">Absolutely Positioned</div>
```

The same way, if you give some value, an equal value, it acts like a margin over the element. That's what I have explained it in the demo above, giving a spacing of `15px` on all the four sides.

In your case, when the element has a fixed `width` and `height`, the element set's its initial `top left` location, but cannot extend beyond the `width` and `height`.

Comment: Please see my  last  problem,still unknown.

Comment: @it_is_a_literature Because you have given `top` and `left` as `0` and not `bottom` and `right`.

Comment: 0 is zero or none , but i can see much more whitespace than none on the screen, the fact that the div was set into screen center violate the rule for which `top:0px; left:0px;right:0px;bottom:0px;` create,still confused.

Comment: would you mind drawing  `top:0px; left:0px;right:0px;bottom:0px;` on my photo ?

Comment: In my opinion that the distance from top to div is much longer than 0px,same thing for left ,right,bottom,how to understand that kind of  contradiction？

Comment: Please draw four lines  to indicate the meaning of  `top:0px; left:0px;right:0px;bottom:0px;` ?

Comment: @it_is_a_literature Well, I am confused.

Comment: Maybe there is a concept of overflow in the `top:0px; left:0px;right:0px;bottom:0px;` ,http://codepen.io/shshaw/full/gEiDt

Comment: @it_is_a_literature I am definitely sure `overflow` is totally different from `position`. Am I wrong?

Comment: In the material `http://codepen.io/shshaw/full/gEiDt`  ,Setting top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0; gives the browser a new bounding box for the block. At this point the block will fill all available space in its offset parent, which is the body or position: relative; container. i think it is the concept of container overflow.With this container overflow concept ,i can understand now.

Comment: Don't it need <code>margin: auto;</code> to let the element is positioned vertically centered?

Comment: @Praveen Kumar Purushothaman  I still don't understand this. In my opinion, If I want to center it, I need code like this `.abs {position: absolute; top: 15px; bottom: 15px; left: 15px; right: 15px; margin: auto; width: 10px; height: 10px; background: #ccf;}` . Please correct me if I was wrong.

Comment: @user8783065 Similar... Please see [Centering in CSS: A Complete Guide | CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/).

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the `width` and `height` styles from the CSS and you will see the difference between `0px` and `50px`. If you set the `width` and `height` of the element, and set the offset to any size (the same size for both `left` and `right` or `top` and `bottom`), it will be centered because the element cannot get any larger than its `width` and `height` attributes.